# What's the convention for documenting functions in PyCharm?

Tags: python, documentation, pycharm

PyCharm gives a template for documenting functions:

```
def silly_function(a):
    """

    :param a:
    :return: 
    """
    return "Silly" if a else "Function"
```

I'm trying to follow Python [docstring convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), but what is PyCharm expecting me to put for `:param a:` and for `:return:`?

If one can point me to a good example, that will be great too.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Python's convention rather than PyCharm's.

You should describe what the `a` parameter represents (ie 'number of even numbers below 10'), then what the return value represents .

Comment: so for `:return:`, will it be `"Silly" or "Function"`?